# How to get the input values passing with the URL in the ajax function using PHP?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I list some values on one PHP page. After that, page scrolling needs to display the remaining values. For this, I added the ajax function on the same page.
I have a ajax call like :

```
page = 1;
$.ajax({
                url: test.php/category/?+"ajaxload=true&page="+page ,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html) {
                }
});
```

From the above function, I passed the ajaxload and page variables.
After that, I tried to retrieve these variables by using

```
$ajaxload = $_GET['ajaxload'];
$page     = $_GET['page'];
```

But I didnt get any value.
I am using the core PHP. So I defined the ajax function and retrieving the input value on the same page.

Comment: I tried with this also. But I got the same result.

Comment: How exactly are you looking at the values? It's not clear

Comment: I want to retrieve the values of ajaxload and page from my ajax url

Comment: That means $ajaxload = true and $page =1

Comment: Just remove the data from the URL and use `data: {ajaxload: true, page: page),` as another property after the `url:` property

Comment: Sorry to say, I know this way. But at this time, I want to pass the input value with the URL. Is it possible or not?

Comment: The default is to do exactly that when you leave `method:` property blank

Comment: I also used this method. But I didn't get the result

Comment: You haven't answered my question

Comment: Again, we need to understand _precisely how you're trying to test that you're getting these values - because your code doesn't show how you're doing it and what you've written (once you've corrected the quote marks to `url: "test.php/category/?ajaxload=true&page="+page` ) should work correctly. So I wonder if somehow you're just not testing it properly, or you've got some script error which is actually stopping the AJAX from running at all. Your description of the outcome is too vague for us to be sure what the code is really doing.

Comment: I am looking at the values like $ajaxload = true and $page =1

Comment: You're still not explaining _how_ you're looking at them. In general, if someone asks you clarify something, it means don't just repeat exactly what you wrote before (which wasn't clear). You're saying these values are not populated, yet the code you've shown should cause them to be populated correctly. A simple test would be: In the PHP write `var_dump($_POST);`. Then in the JS write `page = 1; $.ajax({ url: "test.php/category/?ajaxload=true&page="+page , dataType: "html", success: function(html) { alert(html); } });` and see what you get in the alert box.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the same page for ajaxload at the top you should add the below code

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['ajaxload']) && $_GET['ajaxload'] == true){
    //PLACE YOUR QUERY  and get the result here
    $tr = '<tr><td>'.$result_value_1.'</td><td>'.$result_value_2.'</td><tr>';
    echo $tr;
    exit;
    }
    ?>
```

since ajax call needs an echo so you need to echo the tr of your table. I have used "exit" so that the response of the ajax call does not contain rest of the content of the page

In you ajax function please make sure the url is correct and then append the tr received from the ajax call below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                page = 1;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "YOUR_PAGE_NAME.php?ajaxload=true&page="+page,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#TABLE_ID_GOES_HERE').append(html);
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

I have used table just as reference if your html uses div tags then you can change it accordingly